# How to see asker's name in the top interesting questions list

Tags: support

Is there a way to see the original asker and their reputation in the current front page? It's somewhat confusing to see someone with 41.3K reputation ask how to "call upon a certain line itself of code". [image]

Still, if I knew it was someone with that much reputation, I would be more interested in it myself.

Comment: You might find this interesting: [please implement search filters by minimum rep, etc...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19659/search-filters-by-minimum-rep-maximum-views-maximum-answers-etc)

Comment: The front page shows *active* posts, with the last person to act on the post as the visible user. To view the original questioner, you can [filter by questions only](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion). However, this does not display the reputation.